# NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData float conversion/rounding error?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, json, rubymotion, rounding-error

My simple RubyMotion code:

```
data = DataParser.parse(url)
error_ptr = Pointer.new(:object)
json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: 0, error: error_ptr)
```

The url is a weather API that provides a JSON with temperatures as floats like `{ "temp_c":22.4, ... }`. Strangely exactly that float **`22.4`** gets converted to **`22.3999938964844`**.

If I inspect `data.to_s`the temperature reads `22.4`, so I assume the error lies within `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData`.

- Can anyone confirm this?
- Is there a common solution for this?

I wouldn't like to force rounding of all floats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decimal number "22.4" *cannot* be represented exactly by a binary floating point number such as `float` or `double`. So *"rounding a float to 22.4"* does not make sense, because there is no float that is exactly equal to 22.4.

You can only specify a precision if you convert the floating point number to a decimal string for output. You can use a `NSNumberFormatter` or a printf-format like `"%.<precision>f`.